# EKS Pods being terminated for no reason

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, keda

I wonder if someone can help me.

Kubernetes (K8s 1.21 platform eks.4) is Terminating running pods without error or reason. The only thing I can see in the events is:

```
7m47s       Normal    Killing                   pod/test-job-6c9fn-qbzkb                          Stopping container test-job
```

Because I've set up an anti-affinity rule, only one pod can run in one node. So every time a pod gets killed, autoscaler brings up another node.

These are the cluster-autoscaler logs

```
I0208 19:10:42.336476       1 cluster.go:148] Fast evaluation: ip-10-4-127-38.us-west-2.compute.internal for removal
I0208 19:10:42.336484       1 cluster.go:169] Fast evaluation: node ip-10-4-127-38.us-west-2.compute.internal cannot be removed: pod annotated as not safe to evict present: test-job-6c9fn-qbzkb
I0208 19:10:42.336493       1 scale_down.go:612] 1 nodes found to be unremovable in simulation, will re-check them at 2022-02-08 19:15:42.335305238 +0000 UTC m=+20363.008486077

I0208 19:15:04.360683       1 klogx.go:86] Pod default/test-job-6c9fn-8wx2q is unschedulable
I0208 19:15:04.360719       1 scale_up.go:376] Upcoming 0 nodes
I0208 19:15:04.360861       1 scale_up.go:300] Pod test-job-6c9fn-8wx2q can't be scheduled on eks-ec2-8xlarge-84bf6ad9-ca4a-4293-a3e8-95bef28db16d, predicate checking error: node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector; predicateName=NodeAffinity; reasons: node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector; debugInfo=
I0208 19:15:04.360901       1 scale_up.go:449] No pod can fit to eks-ec2-8xlarge-84bf6ad9-ca4a-4293-a3e8-95bef28db16d
I0208 19:15:04.361035       1 scale_up.go:300] Pod test-job-6c9fn-8wx2q can't be scheduled on eks-ec2-inf1-90bf6ad9-caf7-74e8-c930-b80f785bc743, predicate checking error: node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector; predicateName=NodeAffinity; reasons: node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector; debugInfo=
I0208 19:15:04.361062       1 scale_up.go:449] No pod can fit to eks-ec2-inf1-90bf6ad9-caf7-74e8-c930-b80f785bc743
I0208 19:15:04.361162       1 scale_up.go:300] Pod test-job-6c9fn-8wx2q can't be scheduled on eks-ec2-large-62bf6ad9-ccd4-6e03-5c78-c3366d387d50, predicate checking error: node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector; predicateName=NodeAffinity; reasons: node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector; debugInfo=
I0208 19:15:04.361194       1 scale_up.go:449] No pod can fit to eks-ec2-large-62bf6ad9-ccd4-6e03-5c78-c3366d387d50
I0208 19:15:04.361512       1 scale_up.go:412] Skipping node group eks-eks-on-demand-10bf6ad9-c978-9b35-c7fc-cdb9977b27cb - max size reached
I0208 19:15:04.361675       1 scale_up.go:300] Pod test-job-6c9fn-8wx2q can't be scheduled on eks-ec2-test-58bf6d43-13e8-9acc-5173-b8c5054a56da, predicate checking error: node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector; predicateName=NodeAffinity; reasons: node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector; debugInfo=
I0208 19:15:04.361711       1 scale_up.go:449] No pod can fit to eks-ec2-test-58bf6d43-13e8-9acc-5173-b8c5054a56da
I0208 19:15:04.361723       1 waste.go:57] Expanding Node Group eks-ec2-xlarge-84bf6ad9-cb6d-7e24-7eb5-a00c369fd82f would waste 75.00% CPU, 86.92% Memory, 80.96% Blended
I0208 19:15:04.361747       1 scale_up.go:468] Best option to resize: eks-ec2-xlarge-84bf6ad9-cb6d-7e24-7eb5-a00c369fd82f
I0208 19:15:04.361762       1 scale_up.go:472] Estimated 1 nodes needed in eks-ec2-xlarge-84bf6ad9-cb6d-7e24-7eb5-a00c369fd82f
I0208 19:15:04.361780       1 scale_up.go:586] Final scale-up plan: [{eks-ec2-xlarge-84bf6ad9-cb6d-7e24-7eb5-a00c369fd82f 0->1 (max: 2)}]
I0208 19:15:04.361801       1 scale_up.go:675] Scale-up: setting group eks-ec2-xlarge-84bf6ad9-cb6d-7e24-7eb5-a00c369fd82f size to 1
I0208 19:15:04.361826       1 auto_scaling_groups.go:219] Setting asg eks-ec2-xlarge-84bf6ad9-cb6d-7e24-7eb5-a00c369fd82f size to 1
I0208 19:15:04.362154       1 event_sink_logging_wrapper.go:48] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"kube-system", Name:"cluster-autoscaler-status", UID:"81b80048-920c-4bf1-b2c0-ad5d067d74f4", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"359476", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'ScaledUpGroup' Scale-up: setting group eks-ec2-xlarge-84bf6ad9-cb6d-7e24-7eb5-a00c369fd82f size to 1
I0208 19:15:04.374021       1 event_sink_logging_wrapper.go:48] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"kube-system", Name:"cluster-autoscaler-status", UID:"81b80048-920c-4bf1-b2c0-ad5d067d74f4", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"359476", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'ScaledUpGroup' Scale-up: setting group eks-ec2-xlarge-84bf6ad9-cb6d-7e24-7eb5-a00c369fd82f size to 1
I0208 19:15:04.541658       1 eventing_scale_up_processor.go:47] Skipping event processing for unschedulable pods since there is a ScaleUp attempt this loop
I0208 19:15:04.541859       1 event_sink_logging_wrapper.go:48] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"default", Name:"test-job-6c9fn-8wx2q", UID:"67beba1d-4f52-4860-91af-89e5852e4cad", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"359507", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'TriggeredScaleUp' pod triggered scale-up: [{eks-ec2-xlarge-84bf6ad9-cb6d-7e24-7eb5-a00c369fd82f 0->1 (max: 2)}]
```

I'm running an EKS cluster with cluster-autoscaler and keda's aws-sqs trigger. I've set up an autoscaling node group with SPOT instances.

For testing purposes I've defined an ScaledJob consisting on a container with a simple python script, looping through time.sleep. The pod should run for 30 mins. But it never gets so far. In general it ends after 15 mins.

```
{
            "apiVersion": "keda.sh/v1alpha1",
            "kind": "ScaledJob",
            "metadata": {
                "name": id,
                "labels": {"myjobidentifier": id},
                "annotations": {
                    "cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "false"
                },
            },
            "spec": {
                "jobTargetRef": {
                    "parallelism": 1,
                    "completions": 1,
                    "backoffLimit": 0,
                    "template": {
                        "metadata": {
                            "labels": {"job-type": id},
                            "annotations": {
                                "cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "false"
                            },
                        },
                        "spec": {
                            "affinity": {
                                "nodeAffinity": {
                                    "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": {
                                        "nodeSelectorTerms": [
                                            {
                                                "matchExpressions": [
                                                    {
                                                        "key": "eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup",
                                                        "operator": "In",
                                                        "values": group_size,
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "podAntiAffinity": {
                                    "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": [
                                        {
                                            "labelSelector": {
                                                "matchExpressions": [
                                                    {
                                                        "key": "job-type",
                                                        "operator": "In",
                                                        "values": [id],
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            "topologyKey": "kubernetes.io/hostname",
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                            },
                            "serviceAccountName": service_account.service_account_name,
                            "containers": [
                                {
                                    "name": id,
                                    "image": image.image_uri,
                                    "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
                                    "env": envs,
                                    "resources": {
                                        "requests": requests,
                                    },
                                    "volumeMounts": [
                                        {
                                            "mountPath": "/tmp",
                                            "name": "tmp-volume",
                                        }
                                    ],
                                }
                            ],
                            "volumes": [
                                {"name": "tmp-volume", "emptyDir": {}}
                            ],
                            "restartPolicy": "Never",
                        },
                    },
                },
                "pollingInterval": 30,
                "successfulJobsHistoryLimit": 10,
                "failedJobsHistoryLimit": 100,
                "maxReplicaCount": 30,
                "rolloutStrategy": "default",
                "scalingStrategy": {"strategy": "default"},
                "triggers": [
                    {
                        "type": "aws-sqs-queue",
                        "metadata": {
                            "queueURL": queue.queue_url,
                            "queueLength": "1",
                            "awsRegion": region,
                            "identityOwner": "operator",
                        },
                    }
                ],
            },
        }
```

I know this is not a problem of resources (dummy code and large instances), nor a problem of eviction (it's clear from the logs that the pod is safe from eviction), but I really don't know how to troubleshoot this anymore.

thanks a lot!!

EDIT:

Same behavior with On-Demand and SPOT instances.

EDIT 2:

I added the aws node termination handler, it seems that now I'm seeing other events:

```
ip-10-4-126-234.us-west-2.compute.internal.16d223107de38c5f
NodeNotSchedulable
Node ip-10-4-126-234.us-west-2.compute.internal status is now: NodeNotSchedulable

test-job-p85f2-txflr.16d2230ea91217a9
FailedScheduling
0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector, 1 node(s) were unschedulable.
```

If I check the scaling group activity:

```
Instance i-03d27a1cf341405e1 was taken out of service in response to a user request, shrinking the capacity from 1 to 0.
```

Comment: Are you running the aws node termination handler?

Comment: Hi! thanks for your comment. I'm not, maybe it could help. You suspect this is related to the instances dying? I can see the nodes still up when pods are being terminated

Comment: If the instance isn't terminating, than it's unlikely cluster-autoscaler is a problem as that just handles scaling capacity based on the needs of the scheduler. I suspected aws-node-termination-handler as it will cause nodes to cordone, causing all the pods to reschedule to new nodes.

Comment: I added the aws node termination handler, it seems that now I'm seeing other events:

ip-10-4-126-234.us-west-2.compute.internal.16d223107de38c5f
NodeNotSchedulable
Node ip-10-4-126-234.us-west-2.compute.internal status is now: NodeNotSchedulable

test-job-p85f2-txflr.16d2230ea91217a9
FailedScheduling
0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector, 1 node(s) were unschedulable.

If I check the scaling group activity:

Instance i-03d27a1cf341405e1 was taken out of service in response to a user request, shrinking the capacity from 1 to 0.

Comment: What Kubernetes version are you using? Please check all affinity rules. As I understand as a result you have 2 working nodes and no pods running?

Comment: Ivan, I'm using K8s 1.21 platform eks.4. The affinity rules are visible in the job description above. they are there to place the pods in the correct node and to avoid two pods in the same node. The result after the pod dying is two nodes, and a new pod for the job. The new pod is in pending state until the new node is ready, Later on, the original node node will be terminated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the status of a problem node? Please describe nodes and see if it reports anything (conditions, capacity, allocatable, etc). If there is nothing strange there, SSH into the node and observe kubelet logs to see if it reports anything (if kubelet is running as a systemd service, then journalctl -u kubelet).

Comment: This is the output of  **kubectl describe nodes ip....us-west-2.compute.internal** [gist with command output](https://gist.github.com/raulsperoni/6da8154f06c9ebb0dfd0535cff83a32a)

Comment: What about another node on which pod is being killed? Did you check kubelet logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this was an annoying, small, and tricky thing.

There was another EKS Cluster in the account, but in that cluster, cluster-autoscaler was started like this:

```
command:
            - ./cluster-autoscaler
            - --v=4
            - --stderrthreshold=info
            - --cloud-provider=aws
            - --skip-nodes-with-local-storage=false
            - --expander=least-waste
            - --node-group-auto-discovery=asg:tag=k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled
```

This cluster-autoscaler was discovering all the nodes of the other clusters that had that tag, AND, killing them, after the timeout: 15 minutes.

So the lesson here is, each cluster-autoscaler must be started like this:

```
command:
            - ./cluster-autoscaler
            - --v=4
            - --stderrthreshold=info
            - --cloud-provider=aws
            - --skip-nodes-with-local-storage=false
            - --expander=least-waste
            - --node-group-auto-discovery=asg:tag=k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled, k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/clusterName
```

And all the scaling groups need to be tagged accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I also have a similar problem because of HPA's scale-in.

When you don't write the **minReplicaCount** value, the value is set to 0 as default. Then, the pod is terminated because of the HPA's scale-in.

I recommend you should set the **minReplicaCount** value that you want (e.g. 1).

Answer (score 0):

I it is not directly related to this topic but since then AWS using KEDA und Karpenter to deal with Spot Instance for EKS as explained [here](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2023/05/21/limitless-scaling-and-elasticity-with-kubernetes-event-driven-autoscaling-keda-for-an-event-sourcing-akka-pekko-application-apache-kafka/), by any chance did you converted your Systems to this setup, may be it would perform better for you?